# CRM Online 2015 Dashboards

Tags: charts, crm, dashboard, dynamics-crm-online

Is it possible to have a Sub-Chart?
So, I have a line chart of data, On the vertical access is the user ,and on the horizontal ,displays the total data by month, what I'm trying to do is, if you click on a month , I want it to breakdown per week on horizontal axis, with the user on Vertical axis?

I known you  can drill down, by selecting a field from the dropdown and selecting a chart.[image]

But that's not giving me what i want.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible to do that in easy way.

I would suggest a work around:

- Make additional chart to show (users x weeks) - you can call it a subchart.
- Teach users to use charts like this:

  - Click on the chart (users x months) to pop it out from the dashboard
    to see view+chart
  - Click on the month (that would filter the view to show only the data of selected month)
  - Using chart selector change the chart to show (user x week).

This would give the same result as the drilling you have described but with additional 2 mouse clicks.